# Optimize F-score in e1071 package

Tags: r, classification, svm, libsvm

I'm trying to implement a one class SVM using the e1071 package in R. Can somebody give me pointers on how to optimize the F-score using a grid search ?

I have tried the tune.svm functions but it has only resulted in high sensitivity or high Specificity.

The percentage of positive class which I'm trying to predict is about 1-2% in the general population.

The results i get have high accuracy but with a very low F-score:

```
             Reference
Prediction    members Not members
  members           1           4
  Not members      12         983

           Accuracy : 0.984           
             95% CI : (0.9741, 0.9908)
No Information Rate : 0.987           
P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.83691         

              Kappa : 0.1046
```

Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.08012

```
        Sensitivity : 0.07692         
        Specificity : 0.99595
```

Here are snippets of my code:

```
tuned <- tune.svm(fo, data = df, 
                  nu =  0.001:0.5,
                  gamma = 10^(-2:0), 
                  type='one-classification'                 
                  );

model <-     svm(fo, data = df , 
                   nu = tuned$best.parameters$nu, 
                   gamma = tuned$best.parameters$gamma,
                   type='one-classification'
                 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can provide the tunecontrol parameter of the tune.svm method.

It takes an object of the class [tunecontrol](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/e1071/docs/tune.control).

You then need to create the object with the desired parameters.
By specifying the **error.fun** parameter when building this object you can define the error function to be used.

> **error.fun** :
> function returning the error measure to be minimized. It takes two arguments: a vector of true values and a vector of predicted values. If NULL, the misclassification error is used for categorical predictions and the mean squared error for numeric predictions.

So putting a function which computes the F-Score should do the job.

Comment: I changed my code to add a function for calculating F-score and also modified the tune function:    tuned <- tune.svm(fo, data = df, 
                     nu =    2^(-5:-0.5),
                      gamma = 2^(-6:0), 
                       #cost =  2^(-3:0),
                    tunecontrol = tune.control(sampling = "cross",performances = TRUE, error.fun = FscoreErr(y,prediction)),
                    type='one-classification'                 
                    ) , where FscoreErr is the error function , don't know how to the prediction vector when grid search executes in tune.

Comment: Sorry since i am relatively new to stack overflow, don't know how to put my entire code in the comments here.

Comment: `tuned <- tune.svm(fo, data = df,`
                   `nu =    2^(-5:-0.5),  gamma = 2^(-6:0),`
                   `tunecontrol = tune.control(sampling = "cross",performances = TRUE, error.fun = FscoreErr(y,prediction)),`
                   `type='one-classification'    `             
`                  )