# Use F1 Score instead of Accuracy to Optimize SVM Parameters

Tags: r, machine-learning, e1071

I am using the e1071 'tune' function to optimize an SVM model.  I would like to use F1 instead of Accuracy as the value to optimize for.  I have found on this post: [Optimize F-score in e1071 package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29260407/optimize-f-score-in-e1071-package) that I need to define a new error.fun.  The problem that I am having is that the function that is shown in that post was not shown to ultimately be the solution and it does not work for me.  If I knew the variable names for the predictions from each iteration of tune I could write a function to calculate F1 but I don't know how to get those values.  How can I calculate F1 and use it to optimize model parameters using 'tune' in e1071?  My code is as follows:

```
tuned = tune.svm(PriYN~.,  data = dataset, kernel = "radial", probability=TRUE,  gamma = 10^(-5:-1), cost = 10^(-3:1), tunecontrol=tune.control(cross=10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using {caret} :

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", # choose your CV method 
                     number = 5, # according to CV method
                     repeats = 2, # according to CV method
                     summaryFunction = prSummary, # TO TUNE ON F1 SCORE
                     classProbs = T,
                     verboseIter = T
                     #sampling = "smote" # you can try 'smote' resampling method
)
```

Then tune your model

```
set.seed(2202)
svm_model <- train(target ~., data = training,
                   method = "svmRadial",
                   #preProcess = c("center", "scale"),
                   tuneLength = 10,
                   metric = "F", # The metric used for tuning is the F1 SCORE
                   trControl = ctrl)
svm_model
```

Comment: This works pretty good with my data but it does create a problem that I have not figured out how to deal with.  My data is 316 variables some of which are non-variable of near non-variable in a few folds.  Therefore when I run this code I get problems with "Variable(s) `' constant. Cannot scale data." which is a problem that I do not have with the e1071 implementation.  I think e1071 simply ignores the non-variable features while CARET does not.